# Allow customer to edit a woocommerce order's product quantities

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to allow the customers to edit by they own the product's quantities. This function is displayed in the view-order page.
The code bellow adds the editable quantity fields, but the submition ends with error.( eval()'d code:24 )

```
$order->update_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', $quantity);
```

any idea?

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'edit_order_quantities', 10, 4);

function edit_order_quantities($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text){
$status = $order->get_status();
if($status == 'on-hold' {
    return;
}
$product_id = $item->get_product_id();
$product = $item->get_product();
echo '<div class="order-item">';
echo '<p class="product-meta">' . $product->get_name() . ' - ' . wc_price( $item->get_total() ) . '</p>';
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<input type="number" name="quantity['.$item_id.']" value="' . $item->get_quantity() . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="' . $item_id . '" />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="update_order" value="Update" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';

if(isset($_POST['update_order'])){
    $quantities = $_POST['quantity'];
    foreach($quantities as $item_id => $quantity){
        $order->update_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', $quantity);
    }
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();
    wc_add_notice('Order updated successfully', 'success');
    wp_redirect(wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', $order->get_id() ));
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Well...give us a clue. What's the error?

Comment: eval()'d code on line 24

$order->update_item_meta($item_id, '_qty', $quantity);